# Android Popup Window

Tags: android, activity, popup

Как лучше сделать всплывающее окно, которое можно кастомизировать как угодно?
Видел несколько вариантов того как можно сделать PopupWindow.

```
1. Activity с примененной темой.
2. PopupWindow.
3. Dialog.
```

Но что из этого лучше?

Answer (score 3):

А попробовать, сравнить - вообще никак? ОК.

> 1. Activity с примененной темой.

Из Activity делать всплывающее окно? Бред какой-то.

> 2. PopupWindow.

Самое кастомизируемое, но по этой причине придется слишком много проделать работы в первый раз, словом - "велосипед".

> 3. Dialog.

Кастомизируемое в пределах Theme, как правило этого хватает, вообще-то дизайнера который создаст эксклюзив не на базе Material - еще искать, искать, и искать. И платить, платить, платить.